# SAP Hana - Use JSON parameters in CREATE COLUMN VIEW TYPE HIERARCHY

Tags: json, hana

I'm facing an issue while trying to create a SAP Hana `HIERARCHY VIEW`.
I tried to create it by graphical editor, but it is not working properly (I can't query it). I found a tutorial on Internet explaining how to create it in script. Here is my code.

```
CREATE COLUMN VIEW hier_test TYPE HIERARCHY AS 
    SELECT TO_INTEGER(FATHER_LINK) AS pred
        , TO_INTEGER(ACP_ID) AS succ 
    FROM "_SYS_BIC"."airbus.manufacturing.MES.Projection.base/CV_ZDPGAT_FATH_LINK_ARP_PG" 
    ORDER BY FATHER_LINK
WITH PARAMETERS ( 'hierarchyDefinition'='{"orphanedNodesHandling":"ROOT_NODES","rootNodeVisibility":"ADD_ROOT_NODE_IF_DEFINED"}' );
```

But it's not working properly since I can't find the right value to set to `rootNodeVisibility`. I found these values in the option `Display View XML` from a graphical `Calculation View` having `Hierarchy` set up. But apparently there is no documentation on it...
Could someone give me the way to pass multiple parameters to this script and the different values available for each variable please?
Also, what are the different ways to query the result of this view ? I saw some functions such as

```
SELECT * FROM hier_test;

SELECT * FROM hier_test("expression"=>'descendants(xxxx)');

SELECT * FROM hier_test("expression"=>'subtree(xxxx)');
```

Again, I can't find any documentation on it...

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for why you don't find it documented is that this feature was never released for usage outside SAP. SAP HANA 2.0 will provide SQL commands for hierarchy processing, but with SAP HANA 1.0 there's no official way to use hierarchy views directly outside SAP development.

Comment: Hello Lars. Thanks again for your help. I finally found a way to go with graphical CV. But still I can't understand why this feature is available for use in Hana 1.0 when SAP knows that they won't communicate on it until Hana 2.0... Does that mean that their validation (testing) environment is the same than production one ? :)

Comment: Nope :) The hierarchy feature had been further developed and the initial use cases where explicitly not aimed at SQL level use. As major reworks typically get pushed to later releases, HANA 2.0 eventually became the release the feature ended up in. Not necessarily a technical reason, but more a question of priorities on the backlog.

Comment: And concerning the second part of my question ? (Concerning the SQL queries on a hierarchy) I guess that it is also part of a future release ? Because I need a solution to query this hierarchy... the best would be a function returning a whole branch of a hierarchy for a node (ascendants + descendants in a same query). Do I have to put it in my wishlist ?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK that's what's on the backlog. (don't hold me to it though - I'm not with HANA development...)